# selenium webdriver - NoAlertPresentException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have following piece of code:

```
driver.get(SSO_app_log);
try {
    wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/nav/a[1]")));
} catch (TimeoutException e) {}

WebElement reset_hesla = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login\"]/form/div[4]/a"));
reset_hesla.click();

try { 
    wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
        By.xpath("/html/body/main/section/form/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")
    ));
} catch (TimeoutException e) {}

WebElement email_pro_reset_hesla = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
email_pro_reset_hesla.sendKeys(test_user_email);

WebElement odeslani = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("/html/body/main/section/form/div[2]/ul/li[1]/input")
);
odeslani.click();
```

I get NoAlertPresentException at the line : `WebElement email_pro_reset_hesla = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));`

But there is no switch to alert, even no alert.

In different place of my class there is a switch:

```
try {
    driver.get(SSO_app_log);
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch (NoAlertPresentException a) {}
```

I don't understand, why the exception occures in place, where is no switch. Any help?

versions:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600

webdriver: geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64

Firefox: 59.0.2

JDK: 1.8.0_151

in the exception trace is: Build info: version: '3.8.1'

Comment: Can you update the question with the version info of the binaries you are using _Selenium Client_ version, _WebDriver_ variant & version and _WebClient_ variant & version?

Comment: Update the question with complete code snippet

Comment: updating all binaries nothing changed

Comment: WebElement reset_hesla calls URL to reset login password, so my current workaround is calling the password-reseting URL direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've erased:

```
try { 
    wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
        By.xpath("/html/body/main/section/form/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")
    ));
} catch (TimeoutException e) {}
```

replaced with:

```
try {driver.switchTo().alert().accept();} catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {}
```

and finaly added wait on element email_pro_reset_hesla:

```
WebElement email_pro_reset_hesla = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Email")));
```

got green results